# Mapping array element count in RestKit

Tags: objective-c, json, collections, restkit

I am using RestKit 0.23.

Consider the following HTTP response with JSON body

```
{
    id: 1,
    description: "abc",
    images: [
        {
            id: 1,
            ... a lot of other attributes that I do not need in fact ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following mapping defined

```
RKObjectMapping *responseImageMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: [NoteImage class]];
[responseImageMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: @{@"id": @"imageId"}];

RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: [Note class]];
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: @{@"id": @"noteId",
                                                       @"description": @"noteDescription"}];
[responseMapping addPropertyMapping: [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath: @"images" toKeyPath: @"images" withMapping: responseImageMapping]];
```

This code works fine.
However, the response contains much more data than I really need. I am not instrested in any attribute of image. I only need to distinguish empty array of images and non-empty array of images.

Do I have to define the class `NoteImage` and its mapping if I only need to know whether the image array is empty?

I wonder if I can write something like

```
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: @{@"images#isEmpty": @"imagesEmpty"}];
```

or

```
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary: @{@"images#count": @"imageCounty"}];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this but you should have 2 options, both using KVC:

Best is [collection operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html) so you can use `@"images.@count" : @"imageCount"`

Alternate is to use a custom accessor method, pass it the whole images array and allow it to take the count (or do something else, like take a random item) `@"images" : @"countImages"`

(note that in the custom accessor method approach you need to define a setter an getter, even though you will never use the getter)